# Laravel 5. Adding new table to DB without affecting the data and without re-seeding

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

Laravel 5.5.
I need to add an additional table to DB without loss of data in existing tables. Re-seeding after the "php artisan migrate: rollback" is not suitable, since there is too much data and seeding will last for several days.

Is it possible to add new table without any affect on the existing tables?

Comment: Create a migration and run `php artisan migrate` and that will just run any migrations you have not ran already.

Comment: Oh, so easy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can rollback several steps using

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=2
```

this will rollback last two migrated table